# Проблема с текстовым редактором atom

Tags: atom

Когда я открываю файлы, и закрываю atom, то после открытия все открытые файлы закрылись, а вместо них *unitled*. До переустановки Windows открытые файлы открывались вместе с запуском atom, но сейчас вот такая беда. Что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему через меню *File -> Open folder...* выбрав папку с моим проектом

Comment: В панель задач иконку добавьте. Правый клик по иконке и из `Recent Projects` можно выбрать последний проект.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуй, попробуйте

1. Сохранять проекты, и после этого выходить
2. Посмотреть в настройках самого компилятора, может там надо где-то
   поставить "Галочку"
3. Отключить подсказки в Атоме

Удачи)